# Taking all CGI params and going through and replacing all the values

Tags: perl, cgi

So I have code that looks like this:

```
 use CGI;
 my $q = CGI->new();
 print $q->param('var1');
 print $q->param('var2');
 print $q->param('var3');
```

ect ect..

and what I want to do is if any param contains `(` or `)` I want to replace it with `\(` or `\)`

so if `var1 = "1) blah"` and i `print $q->param('var1');` i get `1\) blah`

Comment: Look at [fetching the names of all the parameters passed to your script](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-THE-NAMES-OF-ALL-THE-PARAMETERS-PASSED-TO-YOUR-SCRIPT:) in the CGI documentation.

Comment: I guess there is a reason you want to backslash? Perhaps, there is a better way to achieve final result.

Comment: yes I need to escape parenthesis so that when it is printed into a file another program can interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for my $key ($q->param) {
    my @vals = $q->param($key);
    if (grep {s/([()])/\\$1/g} @vals) {
        $q->param($key, @vals);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/([()])/\\$1/g for values %{ $q->Vars }
```